# Behavior of ufuncs and mathematical operators differ for subclassed MaskedArray

Tags: python, numpy

I am attempting to subclass `numpy.ma.MaskedArray`, but keep running into an issue where directly using mathematical operators on my subclass behaves differently than directly using the analogous ufunc.  When using the ufunc directly (e.g. `np.subtract(arr1, arr2)`), __array_prepare__, __array_finalize__, and __array_wrap__ are all called as expected, however, when using the symbolic operator (e.g. `arr1-arr2`) only __array_finalize__ is called.  As a consequence, I lose any information stored in `arr._optinfo` when a mathematical operator is used.

Here is a code snippet that illustrates the issue.

```
#!/bin/env python

import numpy as np
from numpy.ma import MaskedArray, nomask

class InfoArray(MaskedArray):
    def __new__(cls, info=None, data=None, mask=nomask, dtype=None, 
                copy=False, subok=True, ndmin=0, fill_value=None,
                keep_mask=True, hard_mask=None, shrink=True, **kwargs):
        obj = super(InfoArray, cls).__new__(cls, data=data, mask=mask,
                      dtype=dtype, copy=copy, subok=subok, ndmin=ndmin, 
                      fill_value=fill_value, hard_mask=hard_mask,
                      shrink=shrink, **kwargs)
        obj._optinfo['info'] = info
        return obj

    def __array_prepare__(self, out, context=None):
        print '__array_prepare__'
        return super(InfoArray, self).__array_prepare__(out, context)

    def __array_wrap__(self, out, context=None):
        print '__array_wrap__'
        return super(InfoArray, self).__array_wrap__(out, context)

    def __array_finalize__(self, obj):
        print '__array_finalize__'
        return super(InfoArray, self).__array_finalize__(obj)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    arr1 = InfoArray('test', data=[1,2,3,4,5,6])
    arr2 = InfoArray(data=[0,1,2,3,4,5])

    diff1 = np.subtract(arr1, arr2)
    print diff1._optinfo

    diff2 = arr1-arr2
    print diff2._optinfo
```

If run, the output looks like this:

```
$ python test_ma_sub.py 
#Call to np.subtract(arr1, arr2) here
__array_finalize__
__array_finalize__
__array_prepare__
__array_finalize__
__array_wrap__
__array_finalize__
{'info': 'test'}
#Executing arr1-arr2 here
__array_finalize__
{}
```

Is there a simple way to get mathematical operators to provide the same behavior as the ufuncs?

Comment: `a-b` should use `a.__sub__(b)`.  Check the `ma` version of that method.

Comment: @Reti43 that's interesting.  I'm on python 2.7.10 and numpy 1.10.1.  I'll have to look at the differences between the two.

Comment: @hpaulj Yeah, I've looked at the special methods for `__sub__` and other similar methods.  They are overridden in MaskedArray and make use of some relatively complex classes that I haven't managed to figure out yet.  It looks to me like the classes they access don't call __array_prepare__ and __array_wrap__ when they should.

Comment: @Reti43 Thanks for the verification.  I'll start digging into the current list of bugs and if I don't find it there will dig into the source again to figure out the change.

Comment: If it helps, for versions up to 1.9.2, `diff2` preserves `_optinfo`. But to be clear, it still only calls `__array_finalize__()`. Version 1.10.0 is the first version where I get an empty dict.

Comment: That helps a lot.  Thank you!

Comment: So far as I can tell, this is a bug introduced in v1.10.0.  I posted it to the numpy mailing list and may submit it as an issue after making a good faith effort at going through the current open issues.  I will also try v1.11.0 tomorrow when I have more time and see if it has been fixed for that release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a legitimate bug that was implemented in the Numpy v1.10.0 release and that is not fixed as of the v1.10.4 release.  [I have submitted this as an issue to the Numpy project.](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/7122)